# Update Model with __construct to limit returned result

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, constructor, model

I have a mode Clients, that user’s database table Clients

```
Id  | active
________________
1   | true
2   | true
3   | false
```

I want to update this model, so that every time Model Clients is called inside my app 
Visitors::get();

It return only those Visitors that has active ==  true

```
class Clients extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = ' Clients ';
…..
public function __construct()....
```

How I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you use a [scope](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes) for that.

```
public function scopeActive($query){
    return $query->where('active', true);
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
Visitors::active()->get();
```

However if you really want, you can use the `newQuery` method:

```
public function newQuery(){
    $query = parent::newQuery();
    return $query->where('active', true);
}
```